# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel every OTHER request

Tags: c#, ssl, webclient

I've read most of the other questions related to SSL/TLS errors. This issue is not with PayPal (as many of the other questions are), and I've tried setting the SecurityProtocol and using a ServerCertificateValidationCallback that always returns true. None of these have changed the behavior, which is that the request completes successfully the first time, then fails, then succeeds, then fails. I can repeat this behavior with every restart of the application.

Here is the code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string url = "https://secure.geonames.net/countryInfoJSON?lang=" +
             HttpUtility.UrlEncode(lang) + "&username=username";
var countryResponse = await client.GetAsync(url);
```

If I make the request to the service using http, instead of https, it works fine every time. If I hit the https URL from Chrome, it works every time. The code above, however, fails every second request. Why?

Here is the stack trace:

```
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.Net.WebException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
</StackTrace>
```

Comment: Is there any local proxy that are set?

Comment: This is tricky, especially since I can't reproduce it. This domain maps to three different IPs. Perhaps your program is round-robin resolving to a different servers and one of the servers is configured in such a way that it fails there, though [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=secure.geonames.net) doesn't report that (even though their TLS is insecure, it should work).

Is there an inner exception? What is the `HResult` of the exception?

Answer (score 0):

check your store for root certificates. And friend found out, that if it exceed a certain amount (think it was 300 or so) not all certificates are available during the applocations lifetime. We had a case, where the connection seemd to randomly fail. Some days ago Microsoft pushed some new certificates to the root store on Windows Server.